# .bat file runs fine in Windows cmd but not with Ansible

Tags: batch-file, ansible, jar

I have some problems to run a simple .bat file from Ansible.
That .bat file is very simple, it just runs a jar.

```batch-file
java -cp "lib\aopalliance-1.0.jar;lib\commons-daemon-1.0.15.jar;lib\commons-io-1.3.2.jar;lib\commons-logging-1.2.jar;lib\joaAlertesJ15.jar;lib\log4j-api-2.17.1.jar;lib\log4j-core-2.17.1.jar;lib\log4j-jcl-2.17.1.jar;lib\mail-1.4.jar;lib\ojdbc7.jar;lib\spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\spring-expression-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\spring-jdbc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\ucp.jar;" fr.joa.alertes.LaunchAlertes >logs\cout.log 2>logs\cerr.log
```

I have no problem when I run it with cmd but with Ansible I encounter some issues. First this is my yaml

```yaml
- hosts: MYHOST
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: Lancement du traitement Alertes J-15
      win_shell: D:\JOA\JOA.AlertesJ15\run.ps1
      register: resultat_commande_alertJ15
      failed_when: 
       - resultat_commande_alertJ15.stderr != ""

    - name: Temps d'exécution du traitement Alertes J-15
      debug:
        msg: Traitement Alertes J-15 réussi et exécuté en {{ resultat_commande_alertJ15.delta }}
      when: 
        - resultat_commande_alertJ15.stderr == ""
```

and this the JSON I can see in AWX after the job "ends"

```json
{
  "start": "2023-07-06 09:18:57.459375",
  "stdout": "\r\nC:\\Users\\myuser>java -cp \"lib\\aopalliance-1.0.jar;lib\\commons-daemon-1.0.15.jar;lib\\commons-io-1.3.2.jar;lib\\commons-logging-1.2.jar;lib\\joaAlertesJ15.jar;lib\\log4j-api-2.17.1.jar;lib\\log4j-core-2.17.1.jar;lib\\log4j-jcl-2.17.1.jar;lib\\mail-1.4.jar;lib\\ojdbc7.jar;lib\\spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\\spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\\spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\\spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\\spring-expression-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\\spring-jdbc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\\spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\\ucp.jar;\" fr.joa.alertes.LaunchAlertes  1>logs\\cout.log 2>logs\\cerr.log \r\n",
  "cmd": "D:\\JOA\\JOA.AlertesJ15\\run.bat",
  "msg": "non-zero return code",
  "stderr": "",
  "changed": true,
  "rc": 1,
  "delta": "0:00:01.354953",
  "end": "2023-07-06 09:18:58.814329",
  "stdout_lines": [
    "",
    "C:\\Users\\batch_crm>java -cp \"lib\\aopalliance-1.0.jar;lib\\commons-daemon-1.0.15.jar;lib\\commons-io-1.3.2.jar;lib\\commons-logging-1.2.jar;lib\\joaAlertesJ15.jar;lib\\log4j-api-2.17.1.jar;lib\\log4j-core-2.17.1.jar;lib\\log4j-jcl-2.17.1.jar;lib\\mail-1.4.jar;lib\\ojdbc7.jar;lib\\spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\\spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\\spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\\spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\\spring-expression-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\\spring-jdbc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\\spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\\ucp.jar;\" fr.joa.alertes.LaunchAlertes  1>logs\\cout.log 2>logs\\cerr.log "
  ],
  "stderr_lines": [],
  "_ansible_no_log": false,
  "failed_when_result": false
}
```

So I don't understand why I end up with `"rc": 1` code and why it is not running the jar correctly. I have tried different ways to find a solution but none of these works :

- Change the .bat file by a .ps1 type
- Modify that line `win_shell: D:\JOA\JOA.AlertesJ15\run.bat` by that

```yaml
win_shell: |
  cd D:\JOA\JOA.AlertesJ15
  java -cp "lib\aopalliance-1.0.jar;lib\commons-daemon-1.0.15.jar;lib\commons-io-1.3.2.jar;lib\commons-logging-1.2.jar;lib\joaAlertesJ15.jar;lib\log4j-api-2.17.1.jar;lib\log4j-core-2.17.1.jar;lib\log4j-jcl-2.17.1.jar;lib\mail-1.4.jar;lib\ojdbc7.jar;lib\spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\spring-expression-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\spring-jdbc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar;lib\ucp.jar;" fr.joa.alertes.LaunchAlertes >logs\cout.log 2>logs\cerr.log
args:
  executable: cmd.exe
```

- Change `win_shell` by `win_command`

And to make it harder to understand the problem, I can run other JAR with a .bat file without problem like this one

```batch-file
%~d0
cd %~dp0
java -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=True -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -cp .;../lib/routines.jar;../lib/activation.jar;../lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar;../lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar;../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar;../lib/mail-1.4.jar;../lib/ojdbc6.jar;../lib/ojdbc7.jar;../lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar;../lib/talend-oracle-timestamptz.jar;../lib/advancedPersistentLookupLib-1.0.jar;../lib/jboss-serialization.jar;../lib/talendcsv.jar;../lib/trove.jar;update_clt_client_to_dwh_0_2.jar; etl_joa_jobs.update_clt_client_to_dwh_0_2.UPDATE_CLT_CLIENT_TO_DWH --context=PROD %*
```

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Why are you running a batch file? Have you tried running `java.exe` with its parameters/arguments instead? The batch file just seems to me to be a wasted step, essentially you are running a file as an argument to cmd.exe in order to run a java.exe, which is a standalone executable, _(i.e. has no need to be launched within an existing cmd.exe instance)_.

Comment: @Compo, you are totally right, i use it because these batch files was present before to launch JAR files with the scheduled task of Windows. I need to change my yaml

Comment: Please do not edit with solution. Remove the solution from your question and add it as a self answer.

Comment: Actually, the correct solution would be to change the working directory for your shell => https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_shell_module.html#parameter-chdir